# Python 3.x Can not write to HKEY_CURRENT_USER (winreg)

Tags: python, python-3.7, winreg

Windows 10 64
Python 3.7 64 [Python 3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 11:52:54) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32]

I have this code that I am trying to write to the registry, but it does not make the changes (Current User).

```
import winreg
testKeyAddress = r"Software\AAA"
key = winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,testKeyAddress)
winreg.SetValueEx(key,"testKey",0,winreg.REG_DWORD,1)
winreg.CloseKey(key)
```

This code works perfectly (Local Machine)

```
import winreg
testKeyAddress = r"Software\AAA"
key = winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,testKeyAddress)
winreg.SetValueEx(key,"testKey",0,winreg.REG_DWORD,1)
winreg.CloseKey(key)
```

What I am missing?  Thanks in advace.

Comment: For me you code works fine. The `testKey` is created in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\AAA`

Comment: I am getting crazy with this, I tried running it with my account, administrator account, the code seems to work but I don't see the values added to the registry.

Comment: Can you confirm that the code works for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` but not for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`? Because if it were the other way around there's a possibility that the key is actually stored under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`. Also is you Python/OS 64-bit?

Comment: the code works fine for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, it does not make the changes on HKEY_CURRENT_USER, I am using Windows 10 64 and python 64 (**Python 3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 11:52:54) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32**)

Comment: Sorry but in that case nothing comes to my mind. As I said your code works fine for me.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue; it's not seeming like it shows up in Registry Editor. I wonder if this answer fixes your issue; it did not for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58439138/registry-key-changes-with-python-winreg-not-taking-effect-but-not-throwing-erro